# Why is a raised to the power of Zero is 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition

Why is $a^0=1$  $\forall a \in Z, a\neq0$. I understand $2^4=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$ How can I express $a^0$. I am serious about the practical proof of this

Comment: It's by definition, it's not something you prove.

Comment: Try starting with the $n$-th root of $a$ and let $n$ tend to infinity: $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: @David: I don't think this has much to do with calculus and limits.

Comment: I assume that you are searching for "intuitive" explanations for schoolboys. If so, I think that Michael Hardy's answer can works. Exponentiation is iterated multiplication; thus, "going back" with repeated division, you arrive at $2^1=2$ and then, dividing again, to $2^0=2^1/2=2/2=1$.

Answer (score 10):

If you want $x^n\cdot x^m=x^{n+m}$ then $x^0\cdot x^n=x^n$. This means that $x^0=1$.

Of course you are free to define it otherwise. But this gives a pretty good motivation why $x^0=1$.

Comment: What does it practically mean? Because $2^4$ means multiplying 2 by itself 4 times

Comment: It means that multiplying $2$ by itself $0$ times gives you $1$.

Comment: @AchariSGanesha Are you asking for some intuition for $n^0=1$? This isn't clear in your question.

Comment: One problem sith this argument took me a long time to appreciate: It's amazing how much lack of an actual feel for algebra can be found in students with some technical skill in its use.  I've posted an answer in a quite different style.

Answer (score 10):

$
2^4 = 16.
$

Divide by $2$ to get $2^3 = 8$.

Divide by $2$ to get $2^2=4$.

Divide by $2$ to get $2^1 = 2$.

Divide by $2$ to get $2^0 = \text{?}$

Comment: I love this intuitive approach - it's very satisfying. Also continues naturally to powers of negative numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simpler than one might expect: it is so by convention.

To understand why the convention is such and not something different, look at this "puzzle": what is the most logical way to continue the sequence 16, 8, 4, 2, ... ? Clearly, the numbers are always halved, so the logical next one is 1. Now, since the sequence is $2^4, 2^3, 2^2, 2^1$, it is only logical to assign $2^0$ the value $1$.

It turns out that this choice is a good one, for example because powers obey the laws you expect them to obey, such as $a^{mn} = (a^m)^n$ and $a^{m+n}=a^m\cdot a^n$ for each $a \neq 0$ and each whole $n, m \geq 0$.

Comment: Oh, how I despise the sentence "What is the most logical way to ...", it sends chills down my spine just to hear it being typed. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's wrong with that sentence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess you must really hate [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQfjIw3mivc), right?

Comment: @Asaf I used to hate this sort of puzzles too. I don't anymore. Pullzles are not really math problems, but they have some good to them. They have a *human* (as opposed to technical) feel to them, and they are good for explaining things on the intuitive level.

Comment: @alexqwx I don't know about Asaf's motivation for that comment, but if it was me, I'd say the problem is that logic is just logic, inferences rules, it's completely independent of what our (us humans) intuition tells us. Some different kind of being could expect $\pi$  to follow after $16,8,4,2$.

Comment: @alexqwx: Because if there's one thing history taught us is that different people, from different backgrounds, find different things to be logical and illogical, and certainly "the most logical".

Comment: @Daniel: I could have lived my life without knowing that song, and now that part of my life is over. Thanks a lot. :\

Comment: @Asaf: Your comments on this answer have brightened my day.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes I am looking for some intuition

Comment: OK everyone, especially the logicians present, maybe it would have been better to replace all occurrences of *logical* in my answer by *humanly* and *nice-looking*. I would have said *natural*, but I'm afraid that would unleash a bunch of angry category theorists on me :)

Comment: I disagree with the statement that this is merely a convention.  It follows from algebra and arithmetic and combinatorics.

Answer (score 6):

when a nonzero number is divided by itself, the result is $1$. Therefore, for example, 
$$2^4\div 2^4=1$$
on the other hand, by the rule of powers, one knows that, for example, $$2^7\div 2^5=2^{7-5}=2^2$$
comparing these two notes we obtain that
$$1=2^4 \div 2^4=2^0$$
hence
$$2^0=1$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
  a^0 &= a^{n-n} = a^na^{-n} = a^n/a^n = 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as an empty product, because $1$ is the multiplicative identity.